# Maven archetype for dynamic web project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm creating a dynamic web project using maven, using this tutorial:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-dynamic-web-project-maven-eclipse-wtp/

It doesn't specify which archetype I have to select in the wizard. Someone can help me?

Note: I'm following this procedure to create the base app to run this other tutorial:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/

Answer (score -2):

Eclipse archetype? If you have fairly recent version of Eclipse, select the 'web' type project, and in the following screen that comes up with something like 'enable Maven support' (don't remember the terminology exactly) select that check box, and you should be good to go.

You also will be able to choose between a Maven-type or Spring-type project directory layout, choose the one you are most familiar/comfortable with. I usually use the Spring format as I've been using Spring longer than Maven and like it better.

Comment: I am running the most current version of Eclipse and Maven and there is no feature of adding Maven support the way you describe it.